# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class Android Studio Kotlin Error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

so i am new at android studio.
so i have 4 activities and on mainactivity i have used startActivity method to open Registration activity.
now when ever i try to run the app the mainactivity is shown but when i click the button "Registration" (i have used setonclicklistener for startactivity) when i click on the button my app crashes and following message is shown

```
 2020-03-30 02:04:35.435 20647-20647/com.example.airlineticketreservation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
 EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.airlineticketreservation, PID: 20647
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
     {com.example.airlineticketreservation/int}; have you declared this activity in your 
     AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
    at com.example.airlineticketreservation.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

and my androidmanifest file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.airlineticketreservation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registration"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        />





    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my mainactivity.kt  file is this

```
package com.example.airlineticketreservation

   import android.content.Intent
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.widget.Button
   import android.widget.Spinner


  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      /* var book_button: Button = findViewById(R.id.book_ticket)
       var name_view:EditText = findViewById(R.id.name_field)
       var cnic_view:EditText = findViewById(R.id.cnic_field)
        var cancellationBtn_mainActivity: Button = findViewById(R.id.cancel_ticket_btn)
       var spinner:Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)

       */
       var registrationBtn_mainActivity : Button = findViewById(R.id.register_btn)

registrationBtn_mainActivity.setOnClickListener {
           var intentx = Intent(this,R.layout.registration::class.java)
           startActivity(intentx)

       }
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
R.layout.registration::class.java
```

with:

```
Registration::class.java
```

You are attempting to use a resource ID as an `Activity` class, and that will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Intent constructor needs two parameters:

1. context, from which your intent will be delivered to the system.
2. class, to which the system will deliver this intent..

In you code, with `R.layout.registration::class.java` you are referencing `resId`, which is not a class object. You can identify it in this part of the log that it takes an `int` value:

```
{com.example.airlineticketreservation/int}; have you declared this activity in your 
     AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So replace `R.layout.registration::class.java` with `Registration::class.java` as:

```
registrationBtn_mainActivity.setOnClickListener {
           var intentx = Intent(this, Registration::class.java)
           startActivity(intentx)

       }
```